# "Malen nach Zahlen" legally protected in Germany?

Tags: trademark, germany, patents

Quoting from a [German wikipedia article about "Malen nach Zahlen"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malen_nach_Zahlen#:%7E:text=Malen%20nach%20Zahlen%20ist%20eine,Arts%20%26%20Crafts%20GmbH%20aus%20N%C3%BCrnberg.) *(or also called "painting by numbers")*:

> Malen nach Zahlen ist eine Wortmarke der Ravensburger AG und des
> Vertriebs Mammut sowie der amerikanischen Dimensions-crafts
> (PaintWorks Paint-by-number), die mittlerweile auch in Deutschland
> erhältlich sind. Ein weiterer Anbieter von Malen-nach-Zahlen-Motiven
> ist die Firma Schipper Arts & Crafts GmbH aus Nürnberg. Die Technik
> wurde von Palmer’s Paint Company erfunden.

But when researching popular competitors, there are a lot of pages offering or selling "Malen nach Zahlen". I have issues with understanding the protection of "Malen nach Zahlen":

- I can't find any Wortmarke - just [one with an image](https://register.dpma.de/DPMAregister/marke/registerHABM?AKZ=012337796&CURSOR=0). "Wortbildmarke"
  in german.
- How can such a term be protected? It describes a way of designing / drawing as a verb.

Either way, all in all my question boils down to: Are you - by this Wortmarke - not allowed to create, publish and market an image with boxes that need to be filled out with specific colors, naming that "Malen nach Zahlen"?

Comment: The word mark, if it exists, would prevent others from using the name "Malen nach Zahlen."  You could make an identical product with a different name.  But I suspect that your research is correct, since Wikipedia authors are often mistaken, and that the protected mark includes an image as an integral component (along with the additional text "jeder kann malen").  In this case, the words "Malen nach Zahlen" would not be protected when used without the image.

Comment: @phoog There are a lot of "Wort-/Bildmarke" in the DPMAregister. But most of them include an appendix - like the one I linked earlier: "Malen nach Zahlen JEDER KANN MALEN". My questions basically is: Can someone make a website and offer "Malen nach Zahlen" (paid or free)? Or is it protected? I've never associated and would have guessed that "Malen nach Zahlen" could and is protected as-is.

Comment: DV: >"I'd need a definite answer whether "Malen nach Zahlen" is comercially protected in the EU (or Germany)." - This steps from "this is an example of a strange situation" to "I want legal advice", which is not allowed on Law.SE

Comment: @Trish I don't. I'm just curious whether I understood the legal topic behind that and whether such a "normal" term can be actually protected.

Comment: + this thread will most likely end up as a good source for a Wikipedia edit. As I highly doubt the information in the Wikipedia. That being said, if I needed legal advice, I'd go to a lawyer :)

Comment: @J.M.Arnold StackExchange sites and other sites with user contributed contents will most probably fail Wikipedia’s necessary _reputable_ source threshold. Moreover _upvotes_ do not necessarily indicate _legal correctness_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> […] I have issues with understanding the protection of "Malen nach Zahlen":
>
> - I can't find any Wortmarke - just [one with an image](https://register.dpma.de/DPMAregister/marke/registerHABM?AKZ=012337796&CURSOR=0). "Wortbildmarke"
>   in german.

A brand can become protected simply by virtue of *using the brand*, § 4 No. 2 MarkenG, if and as far as the brand has reached the status of being a *distinctive* brand within a domain of commerce.
It is *not necessary to officially register* a brand, hence you will not find *all* brands in the national registry.

> - How can such a term be protected? It describes a way of designing / drawing as a verb.

§ 3 (1) MarkenG reads:

> Als Marke können alle Zeichen […] geschützt werden, die geeignet sind, Waren oder Dienstleistungen eines Unternehmens von denjenigen anderer Unternehmen zu unterscheiden.

To paraphrase:
Any brand is eligible for legal protection, if it *is suitable* to distinguish goods or services of one company from goods or services of other companies (in German legalese dubbed *Unterscheidungskraft*).

Conversely, this means there *are* brands that are *not* legally protected, but *still constitute brands*.
You may have misunderstood the Wikipedia article:
The claim “is a brand of Ravensburger” does not make any assertion as to whether it is *legally protected*.

> […] Are you - by this Wortmarke - not allowed to create, publish and market an image with boxes that need to be filled out with specific colors, naming that "Malen nach Zahlen"?

It depends.
Given that the brand is not officially registered, it still may be legally protected brand:
Maybe German (toy/arts supply store) retailers understand *Malen nach Zahlen* (*MNZ*) as a product by Ravensburger (so § 4 No. 2 MarkenG).
If so, you cannot market an *MNZ* product and *name it* like that in the (German) retail sector.
In the end the burden of proof is on the party claiming brand ownership.

> […] My questions basically is: Can someone make a website and offer "Malen nach Zahlen" (paid or free)? Or is it protected? […]

It depends.
As far as I know Ravensburger does not use the brand *MNZ* to offer paint‑by‑number templates *for download* so I say it’s not an issue.

Comment: Why would it matter whether Ravensburger offers their product digitally? I would assume if for example a board game was named and recognized as (lets say) "Da Game!", I would not be allowed to publish this game as an app using this brand name. I can publish an app doing the same thing, but I would not be allowed to name it "Da Game!". Is it different in this case?

Comment: @nvoigt Sorry, I was still thinking about a § 4 No. 2 established brand so the domain of (potential) recipients matters. If it’s a § 4 No. 1 registered brand, it does indeed not matter.

Comment: So in the German retail sector, a Malen nach Zahlen product is legally not allowed? Thus competitors that currently exist - i.e. walking in a toy store right now, there are a couple of competitor brands offering a "Malen nach Zahlen" - do not operate within legal boundaries?

Comment: @J.M.Arnold I wrote _it may be_ a legally protected brand. There _is_ the _option_ that a brand becomes legally protected merely by using it as a brand. Whether or not this is the case today leaves the scope of this site (law.SE [help/on-topic]) as this is not a purely educational question anymore.

Comment: It is, because I don't understand whether this Wikipedia statement results to be true or false. Can we edit the Wikipedia article and reference this a definite source for it?
Is it a legally protected brand or is it not? A "maybe" is not a definite answer to such a question.

Comment: The Wikipedia statement is true. It is a word brand. Let me give you an **example**: Baker B sells her bread in her bakery. The price tag reads _Bread Deluxe_. The phrase _Bread Deluxe_ is a word mark. Therefore a (Wikipedia) statement “_Bread Deluxe_ is a word mark of B” is correct. Regardless of that, _Bread Deluxe_ is not a _legally_ protected brand (in Germany). The name _Bread Deluxe_ does have a distinguishing quality. It is just the common noun _bread_ paired with a (postpositive) adjective. This is insufficient for legal protection. Therefore it cannot be protected under the Brand Act.

Comment: And for my understanding: Why is it then able to be registered as a word mark? Are there no checks for that? Malen nach Zahlen doesn't seem like a brand that a company can legally protect. For me it seems odd, that those companies pay money to get that registered if it doesn't uphold anything legally (or doesn't protect their brand)?

Comment: @J.M.Arnold _Malen nach Zahlen_ (by itself) is not a _registered_ word mark. You yourself have checked the directory. You _can_ obtain legal protection for a brand _by_ registration but that is not the only venue. During registration there _are_ checks. An _unregistered_ brand, however, does not get checked by nobody; only if a judge needs to decide in a trial whether the purported brand owner indeed has a brand enjoying legal protection the question arises. Until then _Wo kein Kläger, da kein Richter._ _nullo actore, nullus iudex._

Comment: You have answered my question. I will attribute you the bounty. But now I'm curious: I searched the directory and there were multiple word marks (or word picture marks)! It seems like the whole brand directory is somewhat of a confusing issue in Germany / EU, isn't it? :)